# how to make my own custom dialog box

Tags: android, layout, dialog, rate

I've downloaded AppRate (https://github.com/TimotheeJeannin/AppRate) and used it to prompt a dialog box asking user to rate the app after a specific # of launches & time elapsed. It is working fine so far..
Only thing is, I want to merge it with a custom made layout (cooked on an XML file) so the dialog box would look, well, different from standard app theme..
IS THAT EVEN POSSIBLE ?

---

code:

```
private void showDefaultDialog() {

    Log.d(TAG, "Create default dialog.");

    String title = "Rate " + getApplicationName(hostActivity.getApplicationContext());
    String message = "If you enjoy using " + getApplicationName(hostActivity.getApplicationContext()) + ", please take a moment to rate it. Thanks for your support!";
    String rate = "Rate it !";
    String remindLater = "Remind me later";
    String dismiss = "No thanks";

    new AlertDialog.Builder(hostActivity)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(rate, this)
            .setNegativeButton(dismiss, this)
            .setNeutralButton(remindLater, this)
            .setOnCancelListener(this)
            .create().show();

}
```

---

thank you so much.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout

Comment: dear Der Golem. I tried that solution but I got tons of errors :p and still trying..

Comment: Dear Zakaria Bouhanna, I use it currently. And have done the weirdest things with it. Without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example, you can write in custom_dialog.xml anything you want

```
public class CustomDialog extends DialogFragment {

public CustomDialog() {

}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(view);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    return dialog;
}
```

}

And for show the dialog, use this code

```
CustomDialog dialog = new CustomDialog();
dialog.show(context, CustomDialog.class.getName());
```